# Add touch events for mobile game

Tags: javascript, touch, touch-event, pointer-events

I am trying to create a game for crossing the road, I did for desktop version where I can move the player by using keys to cross the road, but now I want to do it for mobile version, any idea how to add keys to move the player on mobile devices.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never developed a game - so i'm not sure if you are using jQuery too. If so there is a great plugin for handling mobile devices: https://jquerymobile.com/

Instead of click you have events like 'touchstart' and 'touchend' and you can also directly combine them with click:

```
on('click touchstart,function(){});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can play with touch events in touch enabled devices or you can provide arrows to make movement of object..

[Refer this link of touch event details](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html)

Comment: thank you, but I don't have much experience on this, any idea how to add arrow to make movement of the object.

Comment: Design something like this : http://www.onlywebpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/keyboard_events_in_canvas.jpg

And just bind your movement functions to this arrow click events..